# How to setup the template for 404 error in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to do whatever is written here

> Ensure that your 404 template works
>
> Note that the
>   FlatpageFallbackMiddleware only steps
>   in once another view has successfully
>   produced a 404 response. If another
>   view or middleware class attempts to
>   produce a 404 but ends up raising an
>   exception instead (such as a
>   TemplateDoesNotExist exception if your
>   site does not have an appropriate
>   template to use for HTTP 404
>   responses), the response will become
>   an HTTP 500 (“Internal Server Error”)
>   and the FlatpageFallbackMiddleware
>   will not attempt to serve a flat page.

Can anyone tell me what thing i need to do for making the 404 template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the advice in the tutorial on [setting up 404 handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-404-page-not-found-view).

In particular, presuming you are not going to write your own 404 view, this advice is important:

> If `DEBUG` is set to `False` (in your settings module) and if you didn't create a `404.html` file, an `Http500` is raised instead. So remember to create a `404.html`.

Comment: I'm having a trouble with this :(... If I set Debug to False, I cant get satic files uploaded by users but if I set Debug to True, I can get 404 or 500 templates.

Comment: The problem with static files can be overridden by using --insecure option (I assume you are using manage.py runserver command) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28446999/2843872