# Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page

Tags: python, django, django-templates, http-status-code-404

Following the tutorial found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) exactly, I cannot create a custom 500 or 404 error page. If I do type in a bad url, the page gives me the default error page. Is there anything I should be checking for that would prevent a custom page from showing up?

File directories:

```
mysite/
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
        settings.py
        settings.pyc
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        wsgi.py
        wsgi.pyc
    polls/
        templates/
            admin/
                base_site.html
            404.html
            500.html
            polls/
                detail.html
                index.html
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
        admin.py
        admin.pyc
        models.py
        models.pyc
        tests.py
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        view.py
        views.pyc
    templates/
    manage.py
```

within `mysite/settings.py` I have these enabled:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

#....

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/Me/Django/mysite/templates', 
)
```

within `mysite/polls/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

I can post any other code necessary, but what should I be changing to get a custom 500 error page if I use a bad url?

Comment: Debug is set to False in my code

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12180499/1628832

Comment: Found this answer while looking for the way to make only a custom template and I wanted to share a bit of Django documentation which helped me a lot; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view

Comment: Mine worked without the template_dirs setting.

Comment: Points for irony when link in first line leads to Django's 404 page. Leads to a tutorial page for a version of Django that doesn't exist I think. Here is the link to the tutorial page for Django 2.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 144):

Under your main `views.py` add your own custom implementation of the following two views, and just set up the templates **404.html** and **500.html** with what you want to display.

With this solution, no custom code needs to be added to `urls.py`

Here's the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def handler404(request, *args, **argv):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response


def handler500(request, *args, **argv):
    response = render_to_response('500.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

**Update**

`handler404` and `handler500` are exported Django string configuration variables found in `django/conf/urls/__init__.py`. That is why the above config works.

To get the above config to work, you should define the following variables in your `urls.py` file and point the exported Django variables to the string Python path of where these Django functional views are defined, like so:

```
# project/urls.py

handler404 = 'my_app.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'my_app.views.handler500'
```

**Update for Django 2.0**

Signatures for handler views were changed in Django 2.0:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/views/#error-views

If you use views as above, handler404 will fail with message:

> "handler404() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exception'"

In such case modify your views like this:

```
def handler404(request, exception, template_name="404.html"):
    response = render_to_response(template_name)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

Comment: This seemed to work quite well for me, but for some reason request.user appears fine in the 404 template, but not at all in the 500 template (and they are almost identical) -- posted question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043211/django-custom-500-error-template-not-displaying-request-user

Comment: Another thing I was wondering about -- what if you use the admin backend and want to use separate templates for those? To my knowledge, admin doesn't have a views.py to override and put this bit of code in.

Comment: @GravityGrave the `500 template` won't render `request.user` because it is reporting a 500 server error, so the server is not able to serve up anything.

Comment: Didn't work for me with django 1.9 ;( Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Is handler404 django reserved name? How would django know that it should call exactly that view?

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment. Sorry that the update is so late. I hope that this helps.

Comment: In the first update, you have `handler404 = 'my_app.views.handler404'` but still list the function as being in `urls.py` instead of `views.py`. Note that this won't work unless you move your function to `views.py`.

Comment: `render_to_response` was replaced by `render` in Django 3.0, which automatically uses `RequestContext`, simplifying this answer's example code

Comment: In Django 3.0, `render()` also supports an optional `status` argument, so you can simplyfy the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 112):

## Official answer:

Here is the link to the official documentation on how to set up custom error views:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

It says to add lines like these in your URLconf (setting them anywhere else will have no effect):

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_page_not_found_view'
handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view'
handler403 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_permission_denied_view'
handler400 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_bad_request_view'
```

You can also customise the CSRF error view by modifying the setting [`CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#csrf-failure-view).

## Default error handlers:

It's worth reading the documentation of the default error handlers, [`page_not_found`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view), [`server_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view), [`permission_denied`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view) and [`bad_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#the-400-bad-request-view). By default, they use these templates if they can find them, respectively: `404.html`, `500.html`, `403.html`, and `400.html`.

So if all you want to do is make pretty error pages, just create those files in a `TEMPLATE_DIRS` directory, you don't need to edit URLConf at all. Read the documentation to see which context variables are available.

In Django 1.10 and later, the default CSRF error view uses the template `403_csrf.html`.

## Gotcha:

Don't forget that `DEBUG` must be set to False for these to work, otherwise, the normal debug handlers will be used.

Comment: I did add, but it doesn't work. Added the handler404 and others pointing to right places in my views, yet it doesn't work, still seeing the default 404. And yes, I'm in Debug False mode and using 1.9

Comment: Using Django 1.9 and simply adding 500.html etc templates shows them instead of standard pages. Nice easy fix.

Comment: **Gotcha** helped me. It worked by making these changes in my settings.py, set DEBUG=False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0'] to accept http request from any client.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering where on earth is URLconf, [here it is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: @ArthurTarasov Yeah, would've been better to reference urls.py file along with it haha.

Answer (score 55):

Add these lines in  urls.py

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import (
handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500
)

handler400 = 'my_app.views.bad_request'
handler403 = 'my_app.views.permission_denied'
handler404 = 'my_app.views.page_not_found'
handler500 = 'my_app.views.server_error'

# ...
```

and implement our custom views in views.py.

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import (
render_to_response
)
from django.template import RequestContext

# HTTP Error 400
def bad_request(request):
    response = render_to_response(
        '400.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )

        response.status_code = 400

        return response

# ...
```

Comment: Why would you import `handler400` only to overwrite it with `handler400 = 'myapp.views.bad_request'`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: You don't need to import the handlers here in order to override them.

Comment: You shouldn't use `render_to_response`. From the docs: "it’s not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future."

Comment: For Django 1.10, as `render_to_response` is going to be deprecated, see following (use `render` instead): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228397/django-1-11-404-page-while-debug-true

Answer (score 46):

**Django 3.0+ 4.0+**

here is [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) how to customize error views

here is [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/) how to render a view

in the `urls.py` (the main one, **in project folder**), put:

```
handler404 = 'my_app_name.views.custom_page_not_found_view'
handler500 = 'my_app_name.views.custom_error_view'
handler403 = 'my_app_name.views.custom_permission_denied_view'
handler400 = 'my_app_name.views.custom_bad_request_view'
```

and in the mentioned app (`my_app_name`) put in the `views.py`:

```
def custom_page_not_found_view(request, exception):
    return render(request, "errors/404.html", {})

def custom_error_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/500.html", {})

def custom_permission_denied_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/403.html", {})

def custom_bad_request_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/400.html", {})
```

**NOTE:** `errors/404.html` is the path if you place your files into the projects (not the apps) template folder`templates/errors/404.html` so please place the files where you want and write the right path.

**NOTE 2:** After page reload, if you still see the old template, change in `settings.py` `DEBUG=True`, save it, and then again to `False` and save again (that will restart the server and collect the new files).

Comment: Extra note: If you are running in `DEUB=False` your static files may not be served, making it so you can't preview your custom error template changes.  Use `./manage.py runserver --insecure` to get force django to serve them anyway.

Comment: You need to add `status=<status_code>` parameter to render() calls, otherwise you will get status 200 in the responses. E.g. `status=500` for a 500 page.

Comment: yeah. very important, no matter what 404 pages you have and how good they are setup, you need to disable `DEBUG` in order to see your custom 404 page, this is more like a production only feature (the 404 page)

Answer (score 23):

From the page you referenced:

> When you raise Http404 from within a view, Django will load a special view devoted to handling 404 errors. It finds it by looking for the variable handler404 in your root URLconf (and only in your root URLconf; setting handler404 anywhere else will have no effect), which is a string in Python dotted syntax – the same format the normal URLconf callbacks use. A 404 view itself has nothing special: It’s just a normal view.

So I believe you need to add something like this to your urls.py:

```
handler404 = 'views.my_404_view'
```

and similar for handler500.

Comment: How does that look Mike? Today is my first day using Django and I'm still hanging onto the ropes

Comment: @JimRilye You'll need to add a suitable 500 function to your views, and then reference it with that variable.  So, above your `urlpatterns = ...` line, add a line that says `handler500 = 'views.handle500'`, and then add a `def handle500(request):` to your views.py that displays your 500.html.

Answer (score 21):

In Django `3.x`, the accepted answer won't work because `render_to_response` has been removed completely as well as some more changes have been made since the version the accepted answer worked for.

Some other answers are also there but I'm presenting a little cleaner answer:

In your main `urls.py` file:

```py
handler404 = 'yourapp.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'yourapp.views.handler500'
```

In `yourapp/views.py` file:

```py
def handler404(request, exception):
    context = {}
    response = render(request, "pages/errors/404.html", context=context)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response


def handler500(request):
    context = {}
    response = render(request, "pages/errors/500.html", context=context)
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Ensure that you have imported `render()` in `yourapp/views.py` file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Side note: `render_to_response()` was deprecated in Django `2.x` and it has been completely removed in verision `3.x`.

Comment: In Django 3.0, `render()` also supports an optional `status` argument, so you can simplyfy the answer accordingly.

Comment: This works well, even in Django 4.2.

Answer (score 19):

If all you need is to show custom pages which have some fancy error messages for your site when `DEBUG = False`, then add two templates named 404.html and 500.html in your templates directory and it will automatically pick up this custom pages when a 404 or 500 is raised.

Comment: This works just make sure you have something like: `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<project_name>/templates')]` in your TEMPLATES list in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 18):

No additional view is required. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/views/

Just put the error files in the root of templates directory

- 404.html
- 400.html
- 403.html
- 500.html

And it should use your error page when debug is False

Answer (score 15):

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']  #provide your host name
```

and just add your `404.html` and `500.html` pages in templates folder.
remove `404.html` and `500.html` from templates in polls app.

Comment: How to use message of `raise Http404('msg')`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37109914/895245 `{{ request_path }}` is also available.

Comment: TEMPLATE_DEBUG is removed from django2 https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/django/1.8/migration/template_debug_deprecated.html

Comment: post 1.8: correct way to debug templates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445953/django-app-works-fine-but-getting-a-template-warning-message/32446043#32446043)

Answer (score 14):

In **Django 2.*** you can use this construction in **views.py**

```
def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'errors/404.html', locals())
```

In **settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

if DEBUG is False:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        '127.0.0.1:8000',
        '*',
    ]

if DEBUG is True:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

In **urls.py**

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views
handler404 = 'YOUR_APP_NAME.views.handler404'
```

Usually i creating ***default_app*** and handle site-wide errors, context processors in it.

Comment: Work for me. But what is the `exception`?

Comment: According to the documentation link : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404. It's written : make sure the handler accepts request and exception arguments

Comment: Worked for me in **Django 3.0**. But what is `locals()`? The file only shows `pass`.

Answer (score 7):

Make an error, on the  error page find out from where django is loading templates. I mean the path stack. In base `template_dir` add these html pages `500.html` , `404.html`. When these errors occur the respective template files will be automatically loaded.

You can add pages for other error codes too, like **400** and **403**.

Answer (score 5):

As one single line (for 404 generic page):

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('error/404.html', {'exception': ex},
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request), status=404)
```

Comment: And where to use it?

Answer (score 5):

```
# views.py
def handler404(request, exception):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    err_code = 404
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {"code":err_code}, context)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response

# <project_folder>.urls.py
handler404 = 'todo.views.handler404'
```

This works on django 2.0

Be sure to include your custom `404.html` inside the app templates folder.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your error templates to `.../Django/mysite/templates/`.

I am note sure about this one, but I think these need to be "global" to the website.

Answer (score 1):

In Django root urls.py file, add the below lines

```
from django.conf.urls import (handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500)

handler400 = 'app.views.bad_request'
handler403 = 'app.views.permission_denied'
handler404 = 'app.views.page_not_found'
handler500 = 'app.views.server_error'
```

In your app's views.py file, create the respective functions.

```
def server_error(request, exception=None):
    # return render(request, '500.html')
    return redirect('/')
```

Finally, in your settings.py file, set `DEBUG = False`

Answer (score 1):

I had an additional

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

within my `settings.py` and that was causing the problem.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17662928/2) to the question [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page) by the OP [reZach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837080/rezach) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Django > 2.2

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.template import RequestContext
def handler500(request, *args, **argv):
    context = {}
    print(request.body, '==========')
    response = render(request, '500.jinja', context=context)
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

in urls.py

```
handler500 = 'apps.core.views.handler500'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `urls.py`, enter this code:

```
from django.conf.urls import (handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500)

handler404 = 'my_app.views.page_not_found_view'
```

then add this code in your views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
def page_not_found_view(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)
```

Dont forget to set `DEBUG = False` and also set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [127.0.0.1]` while you are testing in your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything fancy, just create a `404.html` file in your templates. Go to `settings.py` and set:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

It will automatically overwrite the default.

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy Method:

To quickly create a custom error page for the `404` error, place a file named `404.html` in your root template directory. For other errors like `400`, `500`, and `403`, follow the same pattern by creating `400.html`, `500.html`, and `403.html` respectively in the same root template directory

Source: [Django documentation on serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve)

#### Method 2:

To customize error pages in Django, follow these steps:

1. Open your Django root `urls.py` file.
2. Add the following lines to associate specific views with different error codes:

   ```py
   from django.conf.urls import (handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500)

   handler400 = 'app.views.bad_request'
   handler403 = 'app.views.permission_denied'
   handler404 = 'app.views.page_not_found'
   handler500 = 'app.views.server_error'
   ```

   Replace `'app.views.bad_request'`, `'app.views.permission_denied'`, `'app.views.page_not_found'`, and `'app.views.server_error'` with the actual paths to your custom view functions for handling each error.

Source: [Django documentation on customizing error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

> Keep in mind that if the `DEBUG` setting in your configuration is set to `True`, the custom `404` page you create might not be displayed. Instead, Django will show the URL configuration along with debugging information.