# Django custom 500 error template not displaying request.user

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth, django-1.6, django-errors

I'm implementing custom 404 and 500 templates, but while the 404.html template seems to return request.user.is_authenticated fine, the 500.html template fails to return anything. I also checked for request.user and it's just blank on the 500 page.

This is very strange, because when I trigger the 500 error, I receive the expected error report e-mail, and it clearly has USER properly defined in the request breakdown. Here's the code I'm using in views.py:

```
def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response


def handler500(request):
    response = render_to_response('500.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

I'm wondering if something in the background (maybe in RequestContext) is treating the 500 different from the 404? I should mention that I'm also using django-guardian, though I don't think this would affect anything in the case. Any ideas?

**Edit:** [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page/24725091?noredirect=1#comment40798420_24725091) claims "the 500 template won't render request.user because it is reporting a 500 server error, so the server is not able to serve up anything." Does anyone know a way around this? Seems like there should be one because, like I said, the log I receive in the error report e-mail clearly has the request object with the user name.

**Edit 2:** Now I'm wondering if it has to do with django-allauth -- I'm using it as well.

Comment: Try manually passing `'user': request.user` in your dictionary of context variables on your handler500 function.

Comment: @souldeux It doesn't work, unfortunately. What I really need to do is properly pass the entire request object through anyway. Nothing I try seems to work... it's like the request gets scrubbed at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! I had to add the following line to urls.py:

```
handler500 = "mysite.views.handler500"
```

Very strange how the 404 worked fine without an equivalent line, but 500 acts really weird.