# Django 1.8 how to create my own 404 page?

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, production

i want to create my own 404 page.
In settings.py I have added:

```
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
```

In urls.py:

```
handler404 = 'blog.views.handler404'
```

In views.py:

```
def handler404(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/404.html')
```

Also I have created that 404.html file.

When i start server i write:

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

--insecure is to provide static files (otherwise it is nonsense). But if i go non existing page i get:

```
<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /post/9/ was not found on this server.</p>
```

How do I solve this?
I am using Django 1.8 dunno if this changes anything

Comment: You can just put your custom 500.html/404.html in your templates directory and django will use those templates for the rendering instead of the default django templates.

Comment: but it does not work

Comment: Is the 404.html in the same directory as you base.html? Otherwise you template path is incorrect

Comment: Yes, it is in the same dir

Comment: Try setting DEBUG=False and see if that changes anything

Comment: i have tried it with True and False, when it is false i get smth like this: <h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /post/9/ was not found on this server.</p> , when it is True i get standart django debug error page

Comment: yes I have tried that too

Comment: maybe it is somehow different on django 1.8? does anyone knows ho do i solve this nonsense ?

Comment: @pptt - the 404 template is loaded according to the normal rules, so it can depend on the order of the apps in installed_apps - if your app with the templates directory in it comes after contrib.admin, it won't be loaded. Likewise if you're using suit, grappelli or any other library that provides a custom page.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need anything in urls.py. Go to your root views.py and add your handler404 method there, and leave urls.py alone.

Ref: [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page?rq=1)

Also, I don't see your TEMPLATE_DIRS variable, i.e.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/path/to/template/files/',
    '/path/to/more/template/files/' 
)
```

Need to make sure that your templates in ../blog/.. are getting found properly. Personally I'd add that specifically as a subdirectory.

Comment: hello, i have no template dirs variable. i have added new one - TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/templates/blog/'),) it is the same