# Django - get_object_or_404 returns 500 instead of 404

Tags: django, django-views, django-errors

I was trying to test `get_object_or_404` method in my `view`. So I set `DEBUG=False` and set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`.

Now, when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/correctusername/`, it returns a correct profile. The problem is that if I try to write incorrect `username`, it returns `500` instead of `404` - according to name of the functio I suppose that it should return `404`.

```
def get_user_profile(request, username):
    # user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    jobs = user.jobs.all()
    table = MyJobsTable(jobs)

    context = {
        'my_jobs': table,
        "user_": user
    }
    return render(request, 'auth/profiles/my-profile.html', context=context)
```

[image]

Why is that so and how to fix it?

Comment: I would leave DEBUG set to true, that way you will be able to see a more detailed error message of what went wrong. You will still be able to see whether you get an object back, or a 404 error.

Comment: I've check it and it really returns 404 so I don't know why without DEBUG mode it returns 500. Maybe because it can't find 404 html?

Comment: That could be why.

Comment: It could also be that there is an error in the `404.html` template such as forgetting to `{% load static %}` if any url-related items are in the template.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and Milano Slesarik's comment helped me figure out the solution.  It turns out that I recently assigned a custom 404 handler but didn't do it correctly.

Here's what I did *right*:
add following line to `urls.py`.  No need to add `from django.conf.urls import handler404`:

```
handler404 = views.error404
```

Here's what I did *wrong*.  In my `views.py` I added this function:

```
def error404(request):
    return HttpResponseNotFound('custom 404 not found')
```

But I forgot to `import HttpResponseNotFound` in `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
```

So it was raising an exception.  But since I just set `DEBUG=False` I couldn't see the error.  I just saw the 500 response code.

Hope that helps someone!

with the following line in urls.py:

```
handler404 = 'views.error404'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the project has several apps with their own `urls.py` you should add `handler404 = 'app_name.views.my_handle404'` to to the root url conf (that exists in project directory by default)

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution that worked (Django 3.7) dev/prod is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page/#answer-60958882)

Please see @elano7 answer