# Custom Error 400/500 page in Django

Tags: django

There is some strange problem. When I do like this

```
def error_page(request):
    return HttpResponseBadRequest
```

it raises My custom error page that I listed in main URLconf.
But when I pass and exception there - I got just a blank page with the text of exception.
For example, view is something like this:

```
def error_page(request):
    return HttpResponseBadRequest('The error text')
```

And I get a blank page with the "The error text" text in body, but not my custom error page. How can I make Django use my Error page Template, but with error text?

I am using Python 3.5 and Django 1.10.4

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link for creating custom error page. [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)

For passing custom message you can use django messages

Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages


def foo(request):
    # Some view where you want to throw error
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Something Not Wrong')
    raise Http404()
```

And in template you can load the message in th template:

in **400.html**

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Dont forget to set `DEBUG = False` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']` in `settings.py` otherwise Django will catch the error.

Comment: So, that is not a bug or something? Because I thought that there is any other way to solve that problem than making own views to deal with message of error page