# Django 1.11 404 Page while Debug=True

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

**Without making things difficult**, I just want to show a special 404 render with staticfiles.

If you set `DEBUG = False` you can use in **urls.py**

```
handler404 = 'app.views.handler404'
```

But it is without staticfiles. I don't want to install a web server for a simple app.

With `DEBUG = True` in **urls**

```
url(r'^404/$', views.handler400)
```

is not overriding the default ***Page not found (404)*** page.

What is the easy way to achieve a render e.g. when you type *localhost/asdfhjfsda* with staticfiles when *DEBUG=True*?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django 1.10 [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#http-not-found-view):

> Changed in Django 1.9:
>   The signature of page_not_found() changed. The function now accepts a second parameter, the exception that triggered the error. A useful representation of the exception is also passed in the template context.

Have a look at your `'app.views.handler404'` definition, it might miss a parameter, and maybe it's that why the `r'^404/$'`handler doesn't provide you with the correct method invocation.

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way to do this post Django 1.9 is in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

url(r'^404/$', page_not_found, {'exception': Exception()})
```

It wants an exception, give it an exception :)

Answer (score 1):

**I have a complete solution**

**My development environment:**
Windows 7, Python 3.5.2, Django 1.11, WAMP 3.0.6 (Apache 2.4.23, mod_wsgi)

1. *Suppose you have error_404.html template with static files*
2. *Create next directory structure ("mysite" - Django project root folder)*

```
mysite\
        mysite\
                settings.py
                urls.py
                views.py
        static\
                error404\
                          files\
                                 style.css 
                                 image.jpg
        templates\
                   error404\
                             error_404.html
```

3. *mysite\mysite\settings.py*

```
    import os

    DEBUG = False

    TEMPLATES = [{
        ..
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ..
    }]

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = 'FullPathToYourSite.com/mysite/static/'
```

4. *mysite\mysite\urls.py*

```
    from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [..]

    handler404 = views.error_404
    handler500 = views.error_404
```

5. *mysite\mysite\views.py*

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

    def error_404(request):
        return render(request, 'error404/error_404.html')
```

6. *Some Jinjo logic in "error_404.html" (pseudocode)*

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
    ...
      link type="text/css" href="{% static 'error404/files/style.css' %}"
    ...
      img src="{% static 'error404/files/image.jpg' %}"
    ...
```

Comment: I think OP was asking for a solution with `DEBUG = True`