# Setting up http error custom pages in django

Tags: django-views, django-urls, http-error

I wanted to add custom error pages to my website, butI am getting the simple pages, for example the 403 error I am not getting the template I built. template is located in `templates/http_errors/` folder.

my template settings in `settings` file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [normpath(join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import handler403
handler403 = 'core.views.custom_handler403'
```

and `views.py`:

```
def custom_handler403(request):
    response = render_to_response('http_errors/HTTP403.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

I tried a lot of options found on django docs and stackoverflow but could not still find the answer. It would be great if you helped me with this.

P.S. I am using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5

Comment: are you receiving any errors?

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725091/5250746

Comment: I am not getting any errors, HTTP403 is raised but it does not load the custom page I created

Comment: I used that topic to create the view actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These custom pages will only work if you have DEBUG = False in your settings. Otherwise normal debug handlers will be used