# How do I redirect errors like 404 or 500 or 403 to a custom error page in apache httpd?

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, error-handling, httpd.conf

I have created a Django project but I am using Apache as the webserver. Can anyone tell me how can I redirect an error code like 404 or 500 or 400 to a custom error html page instead of getting a standard error message on page in case an error was to occur ? I've tried the solutions available on the web but none seems to work

Comment: what does your .htaccess file look like

Comment: Where should I create the ht.access file ? I had created one which looked like :                                                                             ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry"
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 502 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 503 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 504 /errors.html

Comment: not sure about the double quotes you have but this works: ErrorDocument 404 /yourFilePathGoesHere/404.html Put that in the .htaccess file in the top most directory of the project.

Comment: Okay pal :) I'll try that and let you know. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Just to confirm.. I'm sorry.. I'm a noob in apache and Django.. My Apache httpd directory path is : /etc/httpd...      And my project path is : /var/www/sites/projects...    Where should I create the .htaccess file then ? Because in one doc, I read that I should create the .htaccess file in the apache httpd root directory , i.e /etc/httpd

Comment: put it in your project folder, not the apache directory

Comment: Didn't work buddy :(

Comment: It is better if you share your whole related config, not only ErrorDocument entries, but virtualhost, directories or whatever you have that could be influencing the behaviour.

Comment: Got it pal :) It worked .. Had to set AllowOverride to All from None in httpd.config and DEBUG from True to False in Django settings.py file.. And create views separately for 404 and 502 errors.. In the urls.py, I imported handlers for the errors and that's it.. It works !

Comment: Have a look at this modern answer, which worked for me!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891885/14682396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a blog supported by django,in project's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ....
    url(r'^rss/$', BlogFeed(), name='rss'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemap')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if not settings.DEBUG:
    handler400 = 'common.views.bad_request'
    handler403 = 'common.views.permission_denied'
    handler404 = 'common.views.page_not_found'
    handler500 = 'common.views.server_error'
```

common/views.py:

```
def bad_request(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, '400.html', context, status=400)


def permission_denied(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, '403.html', context, status=403)

def page_not_found(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, '404.html', context, status=404)


def server_error(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, '500.html', context, status=500)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply pal

Comment: Is there a way to pass in permission codes (in case permission check fails) to the context so that it may be displayed in the error page. Thanks.

Comment: you can get what you want inside var `request`, something like `request.user`

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.conf.urls import (handler403, handler404, handler500)

handler403 = 'my_app.views.permission_denied'
handler404 = 'my_app.views.page_not_found'
handler500 = 'my_app.views.server_error'
```

You can handle the requests like this.

Comment: On Django this runs fine.. I am able to redirect to my custom error page but this doesn't work on Apache

Answer (score 0):

The exception missing in a view is a solution for this problem.
Change:

```
def bad_request(request):
```

for:

```
def bad_request(request, exception):
```