# How to redirect using a custom django 404 error view?

Tags: django, url, redirect

I want to redirect users to the login page if they enter an invalid url, but I can only figure out how to render the login page without actually changing the url. Is it possible to redirect with handler404 in django? I have the handler404 in my root URLconf and debug mode set to False. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)

and [Designing Custom 404 And 500 Error Pages In Django](https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/40/designing-custom-404-and-500-error-pages-in-django/)

to redirect your custom url override described method in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)

```
def handler404(request, *args, **argv):
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am interested in redirecting to a home page as opposed to creating a custom error page, but I am not sure if this is possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to django. So i have my URLconf as handler404 = 'app.views.handler404' and my view as def handler404(request): return redirect('home'). Is this correct?

Comment: test it. If throw problem, comment the error traceback

Comment: It's giving me Server Error(500)

Comment: How do I get a more detailed traceback?

Comment: Perfect! I got it to work, I just needed to add an exception argument to the handler404 view and change my home/ url path to a re_path so that it wouldn't get stuck in a redirect loop. Thank you for your help!