# How do I create a Custom response message for 404 Not Found?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to create a 404 Not Found error response with my custom message if the get request in accepts a `jobCategoryId` that has an alphabetic value.

The request format:

```
GET /JobProfilesByCategory/:jobCategoryId
```

**views.py:**

```
class JobProfilesByCategoryView(generics.ListAPIView):    
"""
    A custom view to create a view for Job profile by Category. Lookup_url_kwarg fetches the jobCategoryId variable from the URL 
"""
model=JobProfiles
serializer_class = JobProfilesByCategorySerializer
lookup_url_kwarg = "jobCategoryId"

def get_queryset(self):
    jobCategoryId = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
    print(jobCategoryId)
    if(any(c.isalpha() for c in jobCategoryId)):
        return Response({"detail":"Not Found"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    else:
        queryset = JobProfiles.objects.filter(jobCategoryId=jobCategoryId)
        return queryset
```

**urls.py:**

```
    url(r'JobProfilesByCategory/(?P<jobCategoryId>[-\w]+$)',view=views.JobProfilesByCategoryView.as_view()),#6th API
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`NotFound`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#notfound)

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
...
def get_queryset(self):
    jobCategoryId = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
    print(jobCategoryId)
    if (any(c.isalpha() for c in jobCategoryId)):
        raise NotFound({"custom_key": "Custom Error Message"})
    else:
        queryset = JobProfiles.objects.filter(jobCategoryId=jobCategoryId)
        return queryset
```