# show one page for all error response in django

Tags: python, django

I want to show one special page for all error responses in Django.
as following this issue [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page/24725091) I add these items to my project files. but nothing changed!

**setting.py**

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
```

**urls.py**

```
handler500 = 'app.views.handler500'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def handler500(request, *args, **argv):
    response = render_to_response('app/500.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: @PedramParsian 2.2