# Django doesn't email 500 error when using handler500

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-views

My Django app sends emails correctly to all the ADMINS as long as I don't have a custom error handler.

However, when I add a **handler500** to show my custom 500_error.html page, **no emails are sent**. The 500_error.html page is shown properly. It seems that when you have a handler Django assumes that you take care of the error and thus does not mail anything. (Does this make any sense?)

My questions are:

1. How can I still force Django to send emails even when the handler500 is used?, or
2. How can I get the error description and mail it within my handler500 view function using send_email?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the code of your error handler?

Comment: `def handler500(request):`
`t = loader.get_template('500_error.html')` 
`return HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({'request': request,})))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue was that the function called by handler500 needs to return a 500 status code for Django to sed the email.

Setting this handler sends the email to the Admins and also shows the custom template:

```
def handler500(request):
    t = loader.get_template('500_error.html')
    response = HttpResponseServerError(t.render())
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to show a customized error page, then no handler is required.

Django will search for a template named `500.html` in the root of your templates folder; if available it will be shown. If `DEBUG = False`, an email will be sent.

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view):

> If a view results in an exception, Django will, by default, call the
> view django.views.defaults.server_error, which either produces a
> “Server Error” message or loads and renders the template 500.html if
> you created it in your root template directory.

See also [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)