# Django: How to use handler500 to redirect to a frontend server page and also receive admin error email

Tags: django, email, redirect, internal-server-error

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718803/django-doesnt-email-500-error-when-using-handler500), except my problem is that my frontend page is in another server, an Angular application.

Basically, what I need is to send a redirect response to my Angular frontend when user faces a 500 error, but also would like to receive admin e-mails with stack traces. This only happens when the response is a 500, not the 302 returned by the handler500 redirection.

Answer (score 0):

you can basically send an email and then redirect the user to the URL

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def send_mail():
   ...

def handler500(request):
    send_mail_function()
    return redirect("http://external-site.com/")
```

You can follow this tutorial for email sending.

Comment: Sorry for a late response.
This very email is my point. I don't have a way to generate the yellow exception email with stack trace and everything that Django generates when a 500 happens, in the sense of, what would be the content of that send_mail_function()? Or some other approach.