# Django, how to handle password reset email exceptions?

Tags: django

I am using default Django auth_views + Gmail for password reset. Things works fine for me.

During production if there is error happen with accessing email server ,users get response as internal server error 500. Because Gmail prevent user access.

Instead of internal server error, How can we let users know that the server can't reach email server ?

```
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

Comment: Are you looking for a custom 500 page?

Comment: yes, That would be better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725091/10515390, @crimsonpython24 found answer in this section

Comment: I did not know about custom 500 page, Thanks for the advice, Should I delete question then ?

Comment: Totally up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a global error 500 handler, you should create a custom view for the `accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']` endpoint which inherits from the parent endpoint but places a Try/Catch exception on E-Mail errors and renders a custom couldn't send E-Mail page