# How do you get Django to redirect to another page instead of the login when implementing a permission?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a permission that works on a view:

```
@permission_required('app.admin_foo')
def fooView(request, id=None):
    ...
```

But the default behaviour is to redirect to a login. How can I get Django to redirect to another view when the permission is denied? E.g.

```
return redirect(reverse('bar'))
```

**Update**

For your information, Django can be set up to redirect to a custom 403 page when a permission check fails. See Flimm's answer on this page: [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) decorator accepts a `login_url` parameter, this parameter is the url that the user will be redirected to instead of the default `settings.LOGIN_URL`

```
@permission_required('app.admin_foo', login_url='/foo/')
def fooView(request, id=None):
    ...
```