# Displaying 404 error handling page using django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to handle a 404 http response error on the site. I want my 404.html content to be displayed, but for some reason when I run my local host I do get the response displayed, but my site doesn't look the same as in my contents aren't being displayed as they should. I don't know why this is happening, but I want to make sure I am properly calling in my handler. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My views.py

```
def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'webpage/404.html')
```

My 404.html

```
{% extends "webpage/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<h1>404 Error</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

My Url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('webpage.urls')),
    
]

handler404 = views.handler404
```

Comment: what is your `DEBUG` flag? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view

Comment: I am currently on my local host so I have it set to False

Comment: what do you see instead of 404.html?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page does it help you?

Comment: I do see my 404.html content being displayed. However, my whole site has become white and the overall style of the site has disappeared. Seems like it is not calling in my base.html where it calls in bootstrap and my other features implemented.

Comment: @PawełKordowski thanks for the reference will look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ref to handle the custom error page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

In the main py:
`handler404 = 'app_name.views.handler404'`

In the views add :

```
def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, "webpage/404.html", {})
```

Comment: Would you have any idea why I am getting a whitenoise user warning. I am getting a no directory at my staticfiles?