# Correct way of implementing custom 404 page in Django 3 in production

Tags: django, web

I’ve tried importing and editing `handler404` in `urls.py`, made sure pointed to right template etc but kept getting server 500 error responses. The only way I could get it to work was changing  `return render(` to `return HttpResponseNotFound(` but in that case I only get the text representation of ‘mysite.views.404_error.html’ as need to return HTML directly with `HttpResponseNotFound`. Wondering what is the correct way to return a custom 404 error template. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception

Answer (score 3):

We can render the template with `render_to_string(…)` and then wrap the result in a `HttpResponseNotFound`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def my_404_handler(request, exception, template_name='404.html'):
    context = {}  # some context
    content = render_to_string(
        'some-template-name.html',
        context,
        request
    )
    return HttpResponseNotFound(content)
```

We here thus render a template *`some-template-name.html`*, and the `content`; the result of the function, is then returned with a `HttpResponseNotFound`.

Comment: This looks exactly what I need will try when back at laptop. Thanks a million. Is 404.html a set name that must be used?

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution that worked (Django 3.7) dev/prod is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page/#answer-60958882)

Please see @elano7 answer