# url guarding in django detail view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, detailview

I am trying to fix url guarding issue while using **DetailView** in django web for displaying a particular object (product) details and passing id (pk) to url that doesn't exist in the product model (table) instances. currently it shows Type Error like **"No products found matching the query"** . instead i am looking for a way to display caution page to the user that the required product id doesn't exist.
Illustrated as sample below

models.py

```
from django.db import models

  class Products(models.Model):
       product_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
       product_descript=models.CharField(max_length=200)
       product_price=models.IntegerField()

       def __str__(self):
           return self.product_name
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

  urlpatterns=[  path('product/detail=<int:pk>',views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), 
              name='detail'),]
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Products

    class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
          model=Products
          template_name='food/detail.html'
```

food/detail.html

```
<div>
    <h1>Name: {{object.product_name}}</h1>
    <h3>Descrription: {{object.product_descript}}</h3>
    <h4>Price: {{object.product_price}}</h4>        
</div>
```

Detail page while passing not exist id.

[image: Error messgae]

Comment: When the DEBUG setting is False your app will return a standard 404 response which is pretty much what you are asking for? Or do you want to customised this 404 response?

Comment: actually the thing which i am looking for, to add customized response page.  thanks & regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django, creating a custom 500/404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)