# Django custom 404 page not working

Tags: python, django, error-handling, http-status-code-404

So, in my projects I wanted to add a custom 404 error page, so I followed what I could find on the web, but nothing seemed to work for me.

This is what I have on my files:

settings.py

```
import os
# Django settings for HogwartsMail project.

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
)

handler404 = "HogwartsMail.views.error404"
```

views.py

```
def error404(request):
    return render(request,'404.html')
```

Whenever I try to enter a random url, though, instead of getting a 404 error, I get a Server Error (500).

As I've said, i tried it many different ways, but none actually worked for me.

Also, another problem I am having is that the pages I have load really slowly and they don't open the styling or images, so I assume that, when `DEBUG = False`, I need everything to be already online. Is that correct?

Comment: What's the traceback of 500 error?

Comment: Do not use ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"] in production!

Comment: @user937284 What could be its danger?

Comment: @MohammedShareefC it can provide access to malicious files with forged Host headers in HTTP: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Answer (score 6):

When `DEBUG = False`, you can use `python manage.py runserver --insecure` to serve the static files during local development.

See more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639983/2649824).

Answer (score 3):

In the urls.py of project folder add this where the accounts (it can be any app) is an app of the same project:

**project/urls.py**

```
handler404 = 'accounts.views.page_not_found'
```

In accounts' view add this:

**accounts/views.py**

```
def page_not_found(request):

"""
Page not found Error 404
"""

     response = render_to_response('404.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
     response.status_code = 404
     return response
```

Don't forget to make necessary imports. Also don't forget to change Debug=False in settings.py when testing in staging.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it turns out I don't seem to need to do anything but create a 404.html page. By creating in, when an "Page not found" error is raised, Django will first look for a 404.html in your templates, before using it's own error page. I still have a problem with my static files not being on the web - when set `DEBUG = False` neither the css file nor any of my images appear. Other than that, my problem as fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
def error404(request):
    return HttpResponseNotFound(render_to_string('404.html'))
```

as another example:

```
def error404(request):
    return render(request,'404.html', status=404)
```

Comment: You have not specified in urlpatterns? Try add `('^404/$','HogwartsMail.views.error404')`

Comment: None of this work, I still keep getting a 500 error. Any ideas?

Comment: need to configure the [logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-loggers) or [email reports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports) and put traceback.

Answer (score 1):

As [a best practice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) I've add 2 `urls.py` in my project. So I add `handler404` in my base `urls.py`. my parent `urls.py` is look like this

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404
import myapp

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('myapp.urls')),
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

handler404 = myapp.views.error_404
```

and `error_404` is a view in my `views.py`. like this

```
def error_404(request, exception):
    data = {"name": "somthing error"}
    return render(request,'myapp/404.html', data)
```

check the full tutorial [here](http://thepythondjango.com/designing-custom-404-500-error-pages-django/)